# Change host attribute in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, networking, mysqli

I have an actual problem with mysqli in PHP. Once i have been created method, that changing mysqli object in my class, depending on SQL type. This looks like this:

```
function isSelect($query) {
    $response = substr(str_replace(' ', '', $query), 0, 6);
    if($response == 'SELECT') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private function setRoutes($type) {
    if($type) {
        if(!($this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST_READ, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME))) {
            $this->setRoutes(false);
        }
    } else {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    }

    $this->setEncoding('utf8');
}
```

but i dont want to redefine $mysqli, but want to set `hostname`. In PHP documentation I didnt find function like that. So if you know any setters for mysqli object, help me.

Sorry for my English and Thank you!

Comment: Why not define _two_ connections and store them both?  `$this->mysqli_read` and `$this->mysqli_write`. Decide which to use based on `isSelect()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$this->mysqli->real_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);` to change it?

But that is practically no different than just initializing a new object:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: real_connect requires initializing a mysqli instance using mysqli_init(). I don't think it would work in the above situation.

Comment: No, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php is a method of `mysqli`


You are thinking of `mysqli_real_connect()` which needs the LINK?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can explain my problem. I need to execute two different queries in one connect. SET **@**num := 0, **@**uid := 0 after that select query. So I cant reinitialize this mysqli

Comment: @user212131 Would it maybe be more beneficial to record a unique id number in the Select and then update the same idnum in the other instance? Or Can the write instance also read?